# linux interface to get connected IPs

Tags: linux, networking

Is there an interface to get the currently connected IPs and their state in Linux? I am aware of `ss` and `netstat`, but I want to use `/proc/` or some other "official" kernel interface that already has them (if it exists). If it doesn't exist where would I start to get this information? Basically, I need an interface that has this information so I can retrieve it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides `ss` and `netstat` I currently don't know any other tools that I'd recommend.

For how to get this information:

If you `man netstat`, you can see at the section `FILES` some listed files that netstat uses to collect its information.

Among these, there are `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/udp`.

If you `cat /proc/net/tcp` you can see various information about tcp connections on your system.

A sample output would be

```
sl local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
0: 0101007F:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 11190 1 0000000000000 000 100 0 0 10 0
1: 8700A8C0:91FC 0F02000A:15B3 01 00000000:00000000 02:00000AF6 00000000  1000        0 5565254 2 00000000000 00000 46 4 13 10 -1
```

`rem_address` here is the IP you are looking for. I don't know much about it, but I think `st` gives you information about the current state. `0A` should mean `LISTEN`, `01` means `ESTABLISHED`.

Decoding a `local_address` or `rem_address` is rather easy, `8700A8C0:8F76` for example:

```
Format: hex(rev_ip):hex(port)

87 -> 135
00 -> 0
A8 -> 168
C0 -> 192
:8F76 -> 36726

=> 192.168.0.135, Port 36726
```

More information about the `/proc/net` directory is [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-dir-net.html).

More information about the presented data is [here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html).

A related SO thread is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731656/monitor-the-ip-addresses-from-connections-being-made-from-all-apps-using-the-net).

Answer (score 1):

If you run `strace lsof -i 2>&1 | grep open` you'll get some clues about how `lsof -i` works:

```
open("/proc/1/fdinfo/7", O_RDONLY)      = 5
open("/proc/net/ax25", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/net/ipx", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/net/raw", O_RDONLY)         = 5
open("/proc/net/netlink", O_RDONLY)     = 5
open("/proc/net/packet", O_RDONLY)      = 5
open("/proc/net/unix", O_RDONLY)        = 5
```

Notice a few of the files do not exist on my system.  Some of those files are documented in `man proc`, but their output does not look too hard to understand.

After that, `lsof -i` literally goes through the entire process table, in ascending order, looking for open descriptors:

```
open("/proc/2/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/2/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/3/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/3/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/5/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/5/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/7/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/7/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/8/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 4
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/101/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/112/stat", O_RDONLY)        = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/112/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/143/stat", O_RDONLY)        = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/143/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/3", O_RDONLY)    = 5
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/4", O_RDONLY)    = 5
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/5", O_RDONLY)    = 5
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/11", O_RDONLY)   = 5
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/12", O_RDONLY)   = 5
open("/proc/143/fdinfo/13", O_RDONLY)   = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you are using `iptables` and have `ip_conntrack` compiled into your kernel or loaded as a module, then you can get the `iptables` view of all connection state from `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` or the newer userspace interface tool [`conntrack`](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/)

```
$ sudo cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack
icmp     1 23 src=10.1.1.14 dst=10.1.1.1 type=8 code=0 id=10017 src=10.1.1.1 dst=10.1.1.14 type=0 code=0 id=10017 mark=0 use=2
unknown  2 597 src=10.1.1.10 dst=224.0.0.1 [UNREPLIED] src=224.0.0.1 dst=10.1.1.10 mark=0 use=2
udp      17 17 src=10.1.1.181 dst=10.1.1.255 sport=17500 dport=17500 [UNREPLIED] src=10.1.1.255 dst=10.1.1.181 sport=17500 dport=17500 mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=10.1.1.14 dst=10.1.1.2 sport=22 dport=49218 src=10.1.1.2 dst=10.1.1.14 sport=49218 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
icmp     1 28 src=10.1.1.14 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=13601 src=8.8.8.8 dst=10.1.1.14 type=0 code=0 id=13601 mark=0 use=2
```

This will also include information for connections that are routed through your machine, not just local connections.